# Angular AOT & Rollup - Could not resolve 'app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, rollup

I am trying to complete Angular's AOT tutorial:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Using `ngc` part works and it generates `aot` folder.
However, when it comes to tree-shaking with `rollup` part, I bump into this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve '../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory' from ...\app\main-aot.js
    at Error (native)
    at ...\node_modules\rollup-plugin-node-resolve\dist\rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:78:21
    at ...\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:56:18
    at load (...\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:70:43)
    at onex (...\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:93:31)
    at ...\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:23:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Am I missing something?

@angular: 2.4.4
rollup: 0.41.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular's AOT tutorial seems missing a step; after using `ngc`, it generates only `ts` files in `aot` folder. As the next step, you need to compile these files one more time, to generate the necessary `js` files.

There are two important notes here:

1. You need to compile these `ts` files as `es2015` modules, in order to benefit from "tree-shaking". This means there must be one more config file (`tsconfig-compile-aot.json`) that only points to `main-aot.ts` file.
2. After step 1, all related `ts` files in your project will be compiled as `es2015` modules. If you're using `systemjs` as a module loader and `commonjs` modules in your development environment (as in Angular's tutorials), after using `rollup`, you need to compile your `ts` files one more time as `commonjs` modules, in order to avoid issues with `systemjs`.

Here are the exact steps:

1. Compile your `app.module` with `ngc` and `tsconfig-aot.json` into `aot` folder as `es2015` modules.
2. Compile `main-aot.ts` files with `tsc` and `tsconfig-compile-aot.json`, again as `es2015` modules and generate your `js` files.
3. Pass your entry file (`main-aot.js`) to `rollup`. Now it should generate your output file without any errors.
4. When you want to continue to your development with `systemjs`, compile your `app/ts` files with `tsconfig.json` to convert them to `commonjs` modules again.

---

I have created a demo application that is using these steps:
https://github.com/forCrowd/Labs-Angular-AOTConfiguration

- Install node packages
- Run `gulp` - `default` task
- Open `index.html` for "Development - SystemJS" case
- Open `index-aot.html` for "Production - AOT & Rollup Tree-shaking" case

Also it contains `build-invalid` gulp task that skips this second step, to show that it results in having "Could not resolve 'app.module.ngfactory'" error.

Comment: that's weird. Because the ngc is actually generating js files too in aot folder. It is actually generating factory.js, factory.ts and also .json files with respect to the ts files in the project. I created one more module and compiled that too with ngc and in this case only factory.ts files are generated. I feel that ngc's compilation is not consistent.

Comment: @ShellZero It's been two months since I posted this. That version was 2.4.4 and the current angular version is 2.4.10. Maybe there are improvements in ngc, I didn't keep track of it. But at that time, at least in my case, it wasn't generating any `js` files.

Comment: @coni2k : I was facing the same issue , followed all the above steps but after npm run,I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" . I feel somewhere it is related to Step4. Can you please elaborate the point as I am using SystemJS

Comment: @PratikGandhi Step 4 is actually about converting it back es2015 modules. If you successfully passed Step 3 (rollup), you should be able to run your application in "AOT" version, is that works? If that part is okay, then, when you need to continue to your development, you have to convert them back, but that should be trivial (same as compiling your typescript files when you modify them). It's just, if you forget it and try to run your app, `systemjs` probably is not going to like es2015 modules and will not work.

Comment: @PratikGandhi To avoid confusion; my last comments' first sentence had to be like this: "Step 4 is actually about converting es2015 modules back to commonjs modules".

Comment: @coni2k : I am still not able to solve the issue. I have posted my question along with the code and the commands which I have executed in the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580270/angular-aot-rollup-uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined

Comment: @PratikGandhi Could you put your example on Github and send me the link, maybe I can quickly look at it? Also did you try my example: https://github.com/forCrowd/Labs-Angular-AOTConfiguration

Comment: hi guys, right after the configuration for AOT of the main.ts file the docs actually mention... "Be sure to recompile with ngc!"... I did that and it generated an "out-tsc" directory which contained main.js... I however have a problem now where my rollup-config.js cannot find main.js, and I'm not sure what the execution context of the rollup command is

Comment: my bad I had "out-tsc/main.js" instead of "out-tsc/app/main.js" :)