# Angular AOT & Rollup - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: angular, rollup, aot

I am trying to implement Angular's AOT tutorial:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Using ngc part works and it generates aot folder. However,when I run the application, I get the below error

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

My code is as below :-

tsconfig-aot.json

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
      },

    "files": [
    "src/app/app.module.ts",
    "src/main.ts"
  ],

      "angularCompilerOptions": {
       "genDir": "aot",
       "skipMetadataEmit" : true
     },
     "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "bower_components",
            "typings/main",
            "typings/main.d.ts"
        ]
    }
```

After executing node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json, aot folder is successfully generated.

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';
console.log('Running AOT compiled');
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

I read in one of the SO link that "You need to compile these ts files as es2015 modules, in order to benefit from "tree-shaking". This means there must be one more config file (tsconfig-compile-aot.json) that only points to main-aot.ts file."

tsconfig-compile-aot.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },

   "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 },
 "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Compile main-aot.ts files with tsc and tsconfig-compile-aot.json, again as es2015 modules and generate your js files. On compiling I get my js files
I executed the command
 `tsc src/main.ts`

rollup-config.js

```
import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  dest: 'bundle.js', // output a single application bundle
  sourceMap: false,
  format: 'iife',
  onwarn: function(warning) {
    // Skip certain warnings
    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }
    // console.warn everything else
    console.warn( warning.message );
  },
  plugins: [
      nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
      commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
      }),
      uglify()
  ]
}
```

After that I executed, the below command
node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup-config.js

and then on executing npm run lite,I get the error .

Comment: I don't see the difference between `tsconfig-aot.json` and `tsconfig-compile-aot.json` The first one already has `es2015` module type

Comment: Rollup config should have `main-aot` entry point for production

Comment: @yurzui : Sorry , the difference is in the files section and its just a matter of name . My main.ts content has been changed according to aot and there is no main-aot

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/tree/master/systemjs-ngc-rollup

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code in your master page:

```
window.module = {
    id: 'foo',
    exports: []
}
```

Comment: This seems like it's just patching over the problem and not solving the core bundling error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "exports is not defined" error if you are importing files with extensions other than `.js`. It looks like you might have `.ts` files so you'd need to configure the `commonjs` plugin to look for `.ts` extensions.

The rollup commonjs plugin only searches for files with the `.js` file extension by default. It's not obvious at first but they mention this in their [docs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs):

```
// search for files other than .js files (must already
// be transpiled by a previous plugin!)
extensions: [ '.js', '.coffee' ],  // Default: [ '.js' ]
```

If you're importing files with other extensions then you need to list them in this config.